# Component showing and triggers onclick

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have this component named "ConfirmSave". I have certain condition before I show this component

```
{FormStatus.statusMode === "Success" && (
          <ConfirmSave FormStatus={FormStatus} />
        )}
```

Inside this component I have this

```
const ConfirmSave = () => {
  return ( <div className="col">
  <a
    className="btn confirm-btn yes-sign col"
    onClick={console.log("TEST")} ) > test</a></div>
}
```

My problem is, even the link is not yet click the "onClick" its activating, it saying TEST in my log

Answer (score 1):

Oh i am calling the function not the trigger

```
() => { this.props.removeTaskFunction(todo)
```